# Mongoose and Mongo error, mongoose.connection.host returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I been debugging this weird error in which saving and findone does not work, overtime I suspect the connection is not right so I did a print out

```
console.log(mongoose.connection.host);
console.log(mongoose.connection.port);
```

In which both returns null

This is especially confusing when

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    connStr = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/task_test2';

mongoose.createConnection(connStr, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log ('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    console.log(mongoose.connection.host);
    console.log(mongoose.connection.port);
});
```

There are no errors throwed?

Why is this happening, and how would I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`mongoose.connect`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect) instead of `mongoose.createConnection`.

You'd only want to use `createConnection` if you need more control than you get with the default connection pool provided by `connect`.

So do this instead:

```
mongoose.connect(connStr, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log ('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    console.log(mongoose.connection.host);
    console.log(mongoose.connection.port);
});
```

`mongoose.connection` is the default connection which is why your code was returning `null` for its properties.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I don't quite understand what's the difference, as I have another app using `createConnection` and worked

Comment: @xbd It can work, but if you use `createConnection` then you need to get your models from _that_ connection (e.g. calling `myConn.model`) instead of calling `mongoose.model`.